# How do I keep particular announcements at the top of the list?

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-foundation

I have a pretty basic sharepoint 2010 foundations site that I'm trying to figure out how to keep two particular announcements on top without having to "re-edit" them. I've looked in the list settings and tried creating views, but I haven't seen anything quite like I want yet. I'm also trying to figure out how to make it to where announcments show their entire contents and not just preview it.

Comment: I should add that I want it to show those two announcements on top of all the other announcement on the home page.

Answer (score 1):

One ways is:

1. add new optional column (number or single line of text) on the list.
2. Set that column for those two items.
3. Create a view that will sort based on that column

Comment: I should add that I want it to show those two announcements on top of all the other announcement on the home page.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 different Out-of-Box ways I can think of without having to write any code.

1)  Add a new Choice Column (Yes/No) to your Announcements List called 'Always Show' & set those 2 items to "Yes" , then create a new view in the List called 'Always Showing' with Filters where 'Always Show' = "Yes".  Then in the Page, add a new Announcements List Web Part above the existing one and set it's Default View to 'Always Showing'.  In your default view for the other Announcements List Web Part, you'll probably want to filter it by 'Always Show' = "No" so there's no duplication.

2)  If you want all the announcements in 1 List Web Part, take the Column/View idea above and then add a Sort by 'Always Show' descending, then Title so those 2 will always be on top.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Well, this is sort of working. It shows sorted when I go to "mysite/announcements/Alwaysontopa.aspx" But what I'd like is for it to show in that order when I go to "mysite/default.aspx"

Comment: You'll need to put the default.aspx page into Edit mode, edit that Web Part, and change the default View for the List to use your new View.